# What's the proper way to create a DB with MapDB?

Tags: java, database, creation, mapdb

I have to use MapDb for a Java project but im only familiar with Mysql. Im a litte confused about the creation of the db. My Db should contain user information and posts by user and comments on posts and other similarities. How should i create the Db to make it work like a Mysql db?

Answer (score 0):

here is documentation. You use DBMaker factory:

http://www.mapdb.org/doc/getting-started.html#hello-world

http://www.mapdb.org/doc/db-and-dbmaker.html

Comment: Those links don't exist anymore; do you have the new location?